# Algebra of polynomials over some "function" of indeterminate

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

The usual construction for algebra of polynomials over in indeterminate $X$ with coefficients in a commutative ring $A$ is $A[X]:=A^{(\mathbf{N}^{\{*\}})}$ where $X:=\phi(\delta_*)$, for canonical injections $\phi:\mathbf{N}^{\{*\}}\rightarrow A^{(\mathbf{N}^{\{*\}})}$ and $\delta:\{*\}\rightarrow\mathbf{N}^{\{*\}}$.

Now suppose I want to consider polynomials whose indeterminate is some "function" of $X$. For example, in $A$ I might want to work with expressions of the form $\sum_{i}b_i(x-a)^i$ for some $a,x\in A$ and $b_i\in A$. Does this expression have a counter part in the polynomial ring? First idea is to use $\sum_ib_i(X-a)^i$ but this doesn't make sense since $X$ and $a$ belong to different sets. However this is no problem since we can replace $a$ with $aX^0$ to get $\sum_{i}b_i(X-aX^0)$. Is this what a I'm looking for? I'm not sure.

What should $A[(X-a)]$ look like? In general how does one construct $A[f(X)]$ where $f(X)$ is some algebraic expression of $X$ (e.g. $A[X^2]$ or $A[aX+X^3]$ etc.)?

Comment: The expression $\sum_ib_i(X-a)î$ makes perfect sense, since $X$ and $a$ both belong to the ring $A[X]$. In this ring $X^0=1$ and so indeed you can identify $a$ with $aX^0$.

Comment: And for a polynomial $f\in A[X]$ the ring $A[f(X)]$ is a subring of $A[X]$. Perhaps this is a bit too tautological, but it is the image of the composition map
$$A[X]\ \longrightarrow\ A[X]:\ p(X)\ \longmapsto\ p(f(X)).$$